# Как в ответ на POST запрос получить JSONP ?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Здравствуйте!
Мне нужно послать POST json и получить в ответ jsonp (потому что запрос кроссдоменный).
Пишу так:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8585/?callback=?',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: resuest,
    cache: false,
    success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var value = responseData.someKey;
    },
    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('POST failed.');
    }
});
```

где **resuest** - объект который должен уйти именно в POST, потому что он длинный для GET;
принимает запрос Windows Service который видит в запросе callback и оборачивает ответ в неё.

Проблема в том что **callback=?** в таком виде и остается, а если я что-то задаю, то JQuery её не понимает и соответственно все отваливается с ошибкой

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:12212/cryptoproproxy?callback=?. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Если добавляю

```
dataType: "jsonp"
```

То идет GET-запрос, а мне нужно что бы ушел именно POST, потому что, как я написал, весь объект не влазит в GET (в том плане, что он больше 20000 символов).

И как мне послать данные в POST, и при этом задать **callback** что бы JQuery её понял и корректно обработал JSONP ответ?

Comment: А причем тут callback вообще, если ошибка совсем другая и связана с Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Comment: Так это как раз потому что **callback=?**, а мну нужно что бы было что-то типа **callback=jQuery191022225436801090837_1365514230400**.  
На что приложение вернет JSON обернутый в переданную функцию (JSONP)...  
Вопрос в том как заставить JQuery подставить вместо вопроса после **callback=** рандомную функцию, а потом обработать ответ как JSONP (потому что запрос идет на другой домен и иначе просто я ответа не получу).

Comment: @t1nk jQuery вроде как автоматически подставляет колбек, вам не нужно парится по этому поводу 

И да, POST запрос не пройдет через jsonp по моему.

    $.ajax({
       url: 'url',
       data: {},
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       success: function (data){ console.log(data); }
    });

Comment: В этом и проблема, что если я ставлю **dataType: "jsonp"** то не зависимо от значение **type:** идет *GET* запрос...  
И соответственно объект то же уходит в GET, что не есть хорошо...

Comment: Похоже здесь нужен кэп: jsonp работает только с GET'ом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это невозможно, т.к. JSONP работает лишь по той причине, что нам разрешено вставлять элемент <script> в документ. Возможно какие-то хаки и существуют, но вот это уже не есть хорошо.